# Is there a variable scope that is accessible anywhere in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, scope

I'd like to create something like a very basic chat application. I don't want to use a database, since it'd cause a heavy load on an already strained db. I also don't want to use a flat file, because it have a feeling that it'd become a mess or that it'll have lots of read/writes... 
So, I'm wondering if there is a way to have a variable that is accessible in any file and at any time.

Comment: yes, but not for very very basic chat application. a flat file sounds best fit for such a definition

Answer (score 2):

Well if you don't want a file, you're left with shared memory.

You could try PHP's [shared memory functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php), or use an extension like [memcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) or [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can't share variable values among separate requests - think of each request like the entire program is starting and finishing each time, even if there are several requests happening at once.

You could look into storing data in a cache layer (for example, memcached) however it sounds like you need to cache your database if it's under heavy load. I'd recommend caching your database (again memcached or file-based storage; `serialize()` data first) and then when that problem is solved store the chat data in the database (which is in turn cached). You need to store it persistently somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that I will do this.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such thing. Try creating a basic file that saves [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)/[json'd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) version of the variable you want, use [php's `flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) to manage access to that file, cycle the file every hour/day. Since it's no big traffic simple app, I think this will be okay.